# Cybersource CodeIgniter Session Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, cybersource

Using Secure acceptance for checkout in CodeIgniter Framework but after payment from
`https://testsecureacceptance.cybersource.com/payment`

```
Sometimes it returns to the right response 
(Persists the Session and contains the PHPSSID in the set-cookie request headers)

But sometimes it Logs the user out (The PHPSSID is missing in the set-cookie request headers)
```

How to resolve this unexpected behavior

CodeIgnitor version 3.1.11

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by adding

```
$config['cookie_path'] = '/; SameSite=None';
```

in config.php